# Updating published package in dart pub

Tags: dart, package, publish

This my first time contribute in open source world, I made a simple client for cryptocurrency exchange official API.

I was reading [this](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/publishing) and it's just told me how to publish dart package, I did publish a package, Since I forgot add documentation how to use API Client, I want update `README.md` file. How do I do it? I'm afraid if I do `dart pub publish` will publish packakge twice since `pub.dev` policy don't allow discard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just increment the version number to 1.0.1 or similar and publish again.

See https://dart.dev/tools/pub/publishing